# Print out current aliases in shell

Tags: shell, unix, alias

Is there any way to print out the current aliases on a terminal from a shell script? I know you can simply type in `alias` in the command line and it will print them out, but I need them to print out when I run a script.

Comment: Why could you not have a script that just runs `alias`? Just make it two lines long: `#!/bin/bash` and `alias`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: just type alias in your terminal, that will show the entire list of alias and redirect that to file if you want to save. Don't overdo it.

Comment: Yes, @LethalProgrammer is right and even my simple solution is too long. There _already is_ a script, and it is called `alias`. You can `echo "$(alias)"` in a script if you want.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, there is a shell variable [`BASH_ALIASES`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fALIASES), which is an associative array keyed by alias name and the aliases as values. You can print them, for example, like this:

```
for key in "${!BASH_ALIASES[@]}"; do
    printf '%s=%q\n' "$key" "${BASH_ALIASES[$key]}"
done
```

where the `%q` format specification makes sure that the commands are quoted for reuse.

I'm not exactly sure when this was introduced as the [release notes](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) don't mention it; associative arrays require Bash 4.0 or newer.

Notice that this is a shell variable and not an environment variable, so it is not available in subshells (such as when running a script, non-interactively).

You could do the following, though, assuming that your alias declarations are in a file `~/.aliases.sh`, containing for example this:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

A script could then do

```
source ~/.aliases.sh

for key in "${!BASH_ALIASES[@]}"; do
    printf '%s=%q\n' "$key" "${BASH_ALIASES[$key]}"
done

ll                        # Won't work! "ll: command not found"

shopt -s expand_aliases   # Turn on alias expansion

ll                        # Works!
```

So `BASH_ALIASES` will be populated after sourcing the alias declarations, but you won't be able to actually use them until you've set the `expand_aliases` shell option.

Comment: Another similar way to capture them in an indexed array (if you have bash < `4.0`) would be something like `IFS=$'\n'; a=($(alias | sed 's/^alias[ ]//'))`